# How do I wire up my hexipal?

Tags: broken-age

I've got the wire from <strike>Car'l</strike> Carol, but I can't figure out how to work out the wiring. I'm guessing the clue is somewhere in Vella's side of the story, but

> Vella's stuck in Mom's room now, waiting for Marekai to go outside the ship. The only thing I can interact with is the photo - which has a picture of the hexipal on... but nothing that looks like wiring.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to do is try a wiring and then place the hexipal in the slot next to the door of the spaceship. Symbols will flash up corresponding to which terminals are connected.

On the back of the Hexipad, each of the symbols corresponds to one of the 6 corners of the hexagon.

In my game, this is which symbol was connected to which corner

[image: Hexpals symbols]

A few tips:

1. The wires are color coded.  In the symbols that flash up, the symbols are also color coded.  As I recall, the top row is blue, middle row is yellow, bottom row is red.  These correspond to the rows in the photo.
2. The direction matters.  The left of the two symbols is the side you place first when placing the wires.
3. Initially, the wires are always placed in the same order as the symbol rows.

In my game, the code to activate the hexipal was:

1. Blue Wire: Upper-left to lower-right
2. Yellow Wire: Upper-right to lower-left
3. Red Wire: top to bottom

Comment: These symbols are in a different order to mine - I think it changes from game to game.

Comment: @fredley That wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: @fredley It does indeed change from game to game.

Comment: How did you figure it out? I can't even make sense of your explanation lol.

Comment: @Llamageddon It's been a while since I played it, but as I recall, if you get the WRONG code, the door will in turn flash the code it wants entered.

Comment: @Powerlord Apparently you needed a clue from Vella's side of story, whereas I was trying to complete the individual stories before switching to their counterparts. x.x

Answer (score 2):

The photo in Mom's room has the code for the correst wiring: it's the symbols in the left side of the picture. First, connect the wires in any way you like. Then go to Alex' room, and place the Hexipal in the slot near the entrance. Blue, yellow and red symbols will light up. These correspond to the symbols in the pictue, but they're not in the right order. However, they do tell you which point of the hexagon is associated with which symbol. Then all you need to do is make a note of which symbol is where in the hexagon, and you can connect the wires properly.